# Https net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH for express nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, express, https, greenlock

Im hosting a server on EC2 and I believe I set up the ports correctly to allow on 80 and 443. I'm hosting a flutter app on Firebase hosting, which forces all network communication to go through https which has been a royal pain. When I run everything (on localhost) through http, no problems. I have tried self-certification, but that doesn't seem to work. I am now trying green lock https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock-express.

I followed their tutorials and everything but i'm getting:  net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. Can anyone offer some insight. I'm simply trying to host a static website and I have one call to a server. Maybe there is an easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue, I was using an IP: 12.345.678.90. Instead you have to use a domain: testwebsite.com